# Filtered ObservableList of properties in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-stream

I do have a class:

```
class Person {
    private SimpleBooleanProperty graph = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private XYChart.Series<Date, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();

    public boolean isGraph() {
        return graph.get();
    }

    public XYChart.Series<Date, Number> getSeries() {
        return series;
    }
}
```

which has an extractor of a boolean `graphProperty`

```
private Callback<Person, Observable[]> extractor = person -> new Observable[] {
    person.graphProperty(),
};
```

For showing the series on a XYChart i now need an observable list of all series which have the graph property enabled like:

```
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> filteredSeries = persons
        .filtered(Person::isGraph)
        .stream()
        .map(Person::getSeries)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
```

Unfortunatly the `FXCollections::observableArrayList` is not backed by the person list. So the question is how do I create a correct `ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>` of the person list?

Update:

I tried getting a filted list from persons by

```
FilteredList<Person> graphedPersons = new FilteredList<>(persons);
graphedPersons.setPredicate(Person::isGraph);
```

As @kleopatra suggested I then tried wrapping `graphedPersons` in a `TranformationList`:

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> graphedSeries = new TransformationList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>, Person>() {

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return getSource().size();
    }

    @Override
    public XYChart.Series<Date, Number> get(int index) {
       return getSource().get(index).getSeries();
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return index;
    }
};
```

The chart does not show anything.

Comment: use a filteredList of the persons with a predicate as needed. unrelated beware: don't use series/xydata as in person, it's not shareable (because xydata has a node) - instead, use some kind of custom xy description

Comment: My `XYChart` will accept `XYChart.Series` only as an observable list. The issue is transforming an observable list of `Person` to an observable list of `XYChart.Series`. How would I do that? having a filtered list of persons is already in the code above

Comment: well, actually you don't have a filteredList - you just use it to have a sublist on which you create a new list with the contents mapped from its items :) But that's just nitpicking, you are right: I missed the mapping part. Assuming you want to change the series property on a person and then want the result list reflect that change: not directly supported - but you could implement a custom TransformationList that's backed by the FilteredList. That's rather straightforward, look at its concrete subs for guidance.

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for the suggestion, I saw the TransformationList earlier but was not able to get it working, I posted my current state above, but I have issues getting it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as @klepatra suggested wrapping a filted listin a `TransformationList`

```
FilteredList<Person> graphedPersons = new FilteredList<>(persons);
graphedPersons.setPredicate(Person::isGraph);
```

Transformation List

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> graphedSeries = new TransformationList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>, Person>(graphedPersons) {

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return getSource().size();
    }

    @Override
    public XYChart.Series<Date, Number> get(int index) {
        return getSource().get(index).getSeries();
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
        beginChange();
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                nextReplace(c.getFrom(), c.getTo(), c.getRemoved().stream().map(Person::getSeries).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                nextRemove(c.getFrom(), c.getRemoved().stream().map(Person::getSeries).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            } else if (c.wasAdded()) {
                nextAdd(c.getFrom(), c.getTo());
            }
        }
        endChange();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return index;
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting on-the-fly use of streams - will add to my knowledge base :)